# Large Navigation Header transition is not smooth while scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am trying to build a view controller with collection view that comes with a custom sticky segment control header. Tapping on a segment in the segmented control, will refreshes the data in the collection view and also resets the content offset to zero.

While doing this i ran into an issue with navigation bar transition from large to small and vice versa.. As you can see here, the transition is jumpy and not smooth at all..

[image]

I was able to resolve this issue by changing the below line:

```
edgesForExtendedLayout = []
```

to this:

```
edgesForExtendedLayout = .all
```

But, adding the above line is messing up my attempt to reset the content offset to zero when i tap on a segment in the segment control. As you can see below:

[image]

If its not clear in the above gif, when i tap on the segment, the collection view scrolls along with the navigation bar.. and the content offset is still a bit wrong.. I want to keep the header where it is before the segment was tapped on and only reset the collection view content offset.

I also tried to set `extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars` to true and false but had no effect. I've also tried to play with `contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior` of collection view but not much luck with that as well.

Here's the code where I am setting up the view.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.view.backgroundColor = .white
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    self.navigationItem.title = "Sticky Section Headers"

    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = .all
    self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true

    self.navigationItem.searchController = UISearchController()

    setUpNavBarAppearance()
    setUpCollectionView()
    configureDataSource()
}

func setUpCollectionView() {
    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.bounds, collectionViewLayout: layout())
    collectionView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
    collectionView.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
    collectionView.register(ListCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: ListCell.reuseIdentifier)
    collectionView.register(SegmentedControlSupplementaryView.self,
                forSupplementaryViewOfKind: sectionHeaderElementKind,
                withReuseIdentifier: SegmentedControlSupplementaryView.reuseIdentifier)
    self.view.addSubview(collectionView)
    collectionView.refreshControl = refreshControl
    self.collectionView = collectionView
}
```

This is what I am doing when I tap on a segment in the segment control.

```
@objc func segmentChanged() {
    self.collectionView?.setContentOffset(.zero, animated: true)
}
```

I've also tried to use `scrollTo` methods on collection view but the result has been the same.. I've also tried to set collection view bounds to safe layout guides top and bottom anchors.. that didn't help much either..

Here is the gist file with full code for the view in case if you would like to try it.
https://gist.github.com/prasadpamidi/829e636d4697fda025bb0795ee81e355

There is not much documentation or guidelines around how to do this properly.. I was able to reproduce this with the Apple's sample app itself.

Appreciate any help with resolving this issue..

Comment: Faced the same problem and can't solve it :(